# How to update the object key's value in state using useState() hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a array of objects state that has two key-value pairs `[{name: 'Max', value: 1}]`

when updating the state i am receiving the name from api and comparing with api.name == state.name. if it is true i need to update the value like value + 1. How do i achieve with setState()?

Comment: The key is to not mutate the state. Here's how to [clone an array](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/) or [3 Ways to Clone Objects in JavaScript](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use spread operator, to update the state by only changing the object properties.

```js
this.setState({ array: this.state.array.map((item) => {
  const condition = "..."; // Implement logic
  return {...item, value: condition ? item.value + 1 : item.value }
 })
})
```

Comment: it is not what i wanted, I already did comparisons and gave according conditiions , can you tell me how to update the setState()?

Comment: Can you please then provide some code? And I don't really understand what you mean by saying "update the setState()"

Answer (score 0):

You could update the state like this:

```
    const stateUpdated = state.map((item) => {
      if (name === item.name) {
        return {
          ...item,
          value: ++item.value,
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    setState(stateUpdated);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can update the value as:
>
> //for example below data is coming from api

```
const array1 = [{ name: "Zee" }, { name: "Zee" }, { name: "Zee" }];
```

> //Your state for updating value based on name

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ name: "Zee", value: 1 });
```

> //check is name exist in api data or not if it exist it will increment
> the value

```
array1.map((item) => {
    if (item.name === data.name) {
      setData({ ...data, value: data.value + 1 });
    }
  });



console.log("check=", data);
```